# Find the maximum value of $\sin (A) + \sin( 2A )+ \sin (3A)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

[image: Graph of sin A + sin 2A + sin 3A]
From the graph, it seems that the answer is 2.5. Can someone please help me to solve this problem manually by using trigonometric equations.

Comment: The answer is not actually $2.5$. It would be very hard to solve this problem manually, since (by differentiation) $\cos A + 2 \cos 2A + 3 \cos 3A = 0$ translates into a cubic equation, where you can solve the cubic equation by Cardano's method.

Comment: I don't see why the maximum value isn't $2.5$ though 

Comment: @sai-kartik Maybe not *exactly* $2.5$...

Comment: Is it (really) a math question or you can use a computer algorithm (of yours/us) to find the max value?

Comment: The maximum isn't $2.5$ but instead is approximately $2.49961$. You will not be able to tell the difference by poking around on an interactive graph like that, but there is nevertheless a difference.

Comment: @Ring Ø yeah you're right.. desmos shows me (upon a generous amount of zooming) that it's actually 2.4996

Comment: According to Mathematica, the answer is the root of $729 x^6-4892 x^4+2124 x^2-108$ near $2.5$. It has a radical form $$\frac{1}{27} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{2 \left(41881075861+557442243 i \sqrt{127}\right)}+\frac{9643238\ 2^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{41881075861+557442243 i \sqrt{127}}}+4892\right)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your graph, the maximum seems to appear "close" to $A=\frac \pi 5$. Develop the expression as a Taylor series to get for the function
$$\sqrt{\frac{25}{8}+\frac{11 \sqrt{5}}{8}}+\frac{1}{2} \left(A-\frac{\pi
   }{5}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{5 \left(85+22 \sqrt{5}\right)} \left(A-\frac{\pi
   }{5}\right)^2+O\left(\left(A-\frac{\pi }{5}\right)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, the derivative cancels for
$$A=\frac \pi 5+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5 \left(85+22 \sqrt{5}\right)}}\approx 0.666924$$ and for this value the truncated series gives a maximum of
$$\frac{\sqrt{5}+5 \sqrt{6670+2970 \sqrt{5}}}{20 \sqrt{85+22 \sqrt{5}}}\approx 2.49955$$

The exact solution of the problem is $(0.667291,2.49961)$. Not too bad for a solution obtained without solving any equation beside a linear one.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\sin x+ \sin 2x+\sin 3x \implies f'(x)=12\cos^3x+4\cos^2 x-8\cos x-2]$$
$f'(x)=0$ has three real roots in $[0,2\pi]$ these are $\cos x=-0.8768, -0.2419, 0.7855$$ \implies x=2.6399...,1.8151...,0.6672...$, respectively. the respective values of $f(x)$ are $0.6354..., -0.2423..., 2.4996...$
Finally $f_{max}=f(0.6672...)=2.4996..$